# Postgresql - make the order by correct

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Feels like a silly question.

I have the following query

```
select 'Cardiac - ACS' as a
union 
select 'Cardiac - All' as a
order by a
```

I want the second row "Cardiac - All" appear first by replacing the 'hyphen' character. What should I replace it with? (and how do I find out the order of the symbols and their precedence in Postgres?)

Comment: Why would you want to replace the hyphen? Just get `ORDER BY` right.

Comment: .. it just has to be that way...

Comment: e.g. you can do "select 'Cardiac 1 All' and that makes it come up first.. but that looks ugly... I want another symbol that can come first before "-".....

Comment: So you are looking for a character that sorts before the hyphen? Sort order is dictated by collation rules and depends on your setting of the same (`SHOW lc_collate` to find out).

Comment: @ericbae  what about `select 'Cardiac __ ACS' as a union select 'Cardiac _ All' as a order by a` ??

Answer (score 1):

#### Sort order of characters

Sort order depends on your locale, the [**collation**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html) in particular. Find your setting with:

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

In the `C` locale, characters are sorted according to their byte values. These characters sort before the hyphen (`'-'`):

```
SELECT chr(g)
FROM generate_series (33,ascii('-')) g

chr
---
!
"
#
$
%
&
'
(
)
*
+
,
-
```

The same is ***not*** true for other collations. Test with:

```
SELECT g, chr(g)
FROM   generate_series (33,ascii('-')) g
order  by chr(g) COLLATE "C"
```

The hyphen has a decimal ASCII value of 45.
Remove `COLLATE "C"` to see the effect of *your* current locale.

To find basic candidate characters in your collation, run:

```
SELECT g, chr(g)
FROM   generate_series (1,255) g
ORDER  BY chr(g);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. very much appreciated. I did "SHOW lc_collate" and I got "en_US.UTF-8" and I did the above query and the hyphen came on top!!! looks like I have no other symbol to replace it with!

Comment: @ericbae: Did you try the last query, too? Also, consider other ways to sort your data. Messing with values seems like a bad idea (depending on what you *actually* do). Consider [@Clodoaldo's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25525511/939860).

Answer (score 1):

If there are arbitrary sorting requirements then create a column to sort on:

```
select a, (left(a, position('-' in a)), arbitrary_order)
from (
    select 'Cardiac - ACS' as a, 9 as arbitrary_order
    union 
    select 'Cardiac - All', 0
) s
order by 2, 1
;
       a       |       row       
---------------+-----------------
 Cardiac - All | ("Cardiac -",0)
 Cardiac - ACS | ("Cardiac -",9)
```

The default for the `arbitrary_order` column will be something like 9 or 999 and the arbitrary cases will have lower values.

Or test for the existence of the '- All' string

```
select a, (
    left(a, position('-' in a)),
    substring(a from position('-' in a)) != '- All'
    )
from (
    select 'Cardiac - ACS' as a
    union 
    select 'Cardiac - All'
) s
order by 2, 1
;
       a       |       row       
---------------+-----------------
 Cardiac - All | ("Cardiac -",f)
 Cardiac - ACS | ("Cardiac -",t)
```